# ipython on Mac cannot find python packages

Tags: python, macos, ipython

I have installed ipython 3.0.0-b1 on Mac OS 10.7.5 (in `/usr/local/bin/ipython2`), and matplotlib, using pip.

If I use `python` (which runs version 2.7.3), `import matplotlib` works fine.

If I use `ipython2`, then `import matplotlib` complains:

```
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

How can I get ipython to find my installed packages? Thanks!

Comment: `python`  and `ipython2` probably belong to different python interpreters. You have several options to fix that. You could e.g. install try to install matplotlib via `ipython2 -m pip -- install matplotlib`. I would suggest switching to `anaconda`, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your `pip` command and got `Requires numpy 1.6 or later to build.  (Found 1.5.1)`; so I tried `ipython2 -m pip -- install numpy==1.9.1` and got `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy==1.9.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`... is there a way around this?  Thanks for the ref to anaconda - I hadn't heard of it - though I'm a bit hesitant to bring in a whole new package manager. On my MacBook I'm having no problems using ipython notebook.

Comment: I just tried using [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), and got it all up and running very quickly. Also pleased to have found spyder to use as an IDE. Thanks!